# Computing operations counter in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that is 400, I need to subtract 30 from it every time, while it’s possible, and in the end, I get the result and the number of computational operations, and after rewrite data of this object
Example: 400 - (30 * 13) = 10 and 13 subtractions were made
Made code example with hp/dmg

```
var hp = 400;
var dmg = 30;
while (hp > 0) {
    hp = hp - dmg
}
console.log(hp)
```

but I need add counter and I have no idea how to did it

Comment: It's just another variable like your hp variable, except you set it's value to 0 to begin with and then you increase it by one each time

Comment: Yep, I understand, but I can't imagine how to make this

Comment: Which bit is difficult? You know how to make a new variable, because it's the same type of line as your `var hp...` line. And you surely know how to add 1 to the value. Clue: it's very similar to how you subtract from the hp variable, except you are adding ( + instead of -). Come on, you can at least _try_ it based on that. This is a super simple example even for a beginner. Best way to learn is by trying, not by people just telling you the answer immediately (so ignore the solution below until you've at least had a go yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without loop:

```
var let = 400;
var let = 30;   
console.log(Math.floor(hp/dmg))             //13
console.log(hp - dmg * Math.floor(hp/dmg))  //10
```

Comment: Thank you for the original idea!

Answer (score 1):

I should be something like this if I understand your question right:

```js
var hp = 400;
var dmg = 30;
count = 0;
while (hp >0) {
  hp = hp - dmg;
  count++;
}
console.log(hp)
console.log(count)
```

Comment: I'd image that count should start at zero